# how to call member function of a member variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm really new to ruby, and I'm trying to do a project that is due soon.

I got the error `"undefined method 'new_round' for nil:NilClass"` and have no idea about what's going on. Wish someone would help me out. Thanks a lot.

```
class Blackjack
  def initialize()
    @deck = Deck.new(gets.to_i())
    @dealer = Dealer.new()
    @players = []
  end

  def new_round()
  end
end

class Controller
  def initializer()
    @blackjack = Blackjack.new()
  end

  def run()
    loop do
      @blackjack.new_round()
    end 
  end
end

Controller.new().run()
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `initializer()` to `initialize()` :)

You get `undefined method 'new_round' for nil:NilClass` because `@blackjack` is `nil`.

`@blackjack` is `nil` because the `initializer()` method is not being called.